# Putting minor ticks in both top and bottom x-axis when using set_xlim command

Tags: python, matplotlib

For visual appeal I was trying to put minor tick labels on both the upper and lower x axis. I used axs[i].xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(10)) as well as axs[0].set_xticks([2, 1, 0, -1, -2], minor=True). just using autominorlocator is not producing any minor tick labels in the 2nd subplot when I put minor=True in set_xticks, I am getting the minor ticks but the labels also changes to include 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 instead of 1, 2.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

x1 = np.linspace(2, -2, 5)
y1 = np.linspace(-2, 2, 5)

x2 = np.linspace(1, -5, 7)
y2 = np.linspace(-5, 1, 7)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(14, 10))
fig.suptitle('With minor x ticks')

# plot 1 (a)
axs[0].plot(x1, y1)
axs[0].set_ylim(-2, 2)
axs[0].set_xlim(2, -2)
axs[0].set_xticks([2, 1, 0, -1, -2], minor=True)
axs[0].set_yticks([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
axs[0].set_box_aspect(1)

# plot 1 (b)
axs[1].plot(x2, y2)
axs[1].set_ylim(-5, 1)
axs[1].set_ylim(1, -5)
axs[1].set_xticks([1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5], minor=True)
axs[1].set_yticks([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1])
axs[1].set_box_aspect(1)

for i in range(2):
    axs[i].yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(10))
    axs[i].xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(10))
    axs[i].yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
    axs[i].xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
    axs[i].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', direction='in')
plt.show()
fig.savefig("fig1_with minor.pdf")
```

[image])

Comment: Maybe you could try `set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))` and `set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))`?